# Java: NotifyObserver and DeadLock in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller, deadlock

I have a problem with Observer-Pattern and deadlock using threads.

```
package observerDeadLock;

import java.util.Observable;

public class MyModel extends Observable {
Integer foo;

public MyModel() {
    foo = 0;
}

public void changeStatus(Integer newStatus) {
    foo = newStatus;
    notifyObservers(newStatus);     
}
}
```

---

```
package observerDeadLock;

public class Job extends Thread {
    public MyModel model;

    public Job(MyModel model) {
        super();

        this.model = model;
    }

    public void run() {
        prepareJob();
        runMyJob();
    }

    private void runMyJob() {
        // Some stuff
        Integer choice = 1;

        if (choice == 3) {
            return;
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            return;
        }
        else if (choice == 1) {                                     
            model.changeStatus(123);    // Set a particalar status that MyController receive as wrong!
                    // PROBLEM: The Controller listen the changeStatus(123) of notifyObserver of MyModel and call a join() because I want the thread join and quit()
            return; // <<- NEVER EXECUTED! join(timeout) isn't the solution IHMO...s
        }       

        return;
    }

    private void prepareJob() {
        // Do some stuff
    }
```

### }

```
package observerDeadLock;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class MyController implements Observer {
    private Job myJob;
    private MyModel model;

    public MyController() {

    }

    public void startJob() {
        model = new MyModel();
        model.addObserver(this);

        myJob = new Job(model);
        myJob.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if (o instanceof MyModel) {
            if (((Integer) arg) == 1) {     
                // do other stuff
            }
            else if (((Integer) arg) == 2) {        
                // do other stuff
            }
            else if (((Integer) arg) == 123) {      // 123 => Wrong state for myController, so must stop Job
                // Stop myJob!!!
                try {
                    //myJob.join(timeout); // isn' the solution IHMO

                    myJob.join();               // PROBLEM HERE!!! In job, the "return" statment is locked in changeStatus() -> myModel.notifyobserver() that lock here in JOIN();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
            }


        }
    }
}
```

What I can do to resolve that problem? I suppose that use Thread.join() than Thread.interrupt() is a bad practice...
Suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't your observer called from the same thread you're trying to join?

Comment: Yes, this is my problem, because when MyController receive a change in status of Model, do some stuff (process next element, ecc). MyController is a class that represent an ipotetically QueueJobProcessor()

Comment: I think that I can add a new class that changeStatus() in another separate thread..Eg: create a setStatus() that spawn a thread for changing status...but I think its too expensive and a bad practice..

Comment: Sure, I'm already study a decent implementation of this problem, but I think isn't a design problem...So..notifyObserver() and a join() cannot be used. In this case I think that I avoid to call join() on thread because isn't necessary..When the changeStatus() is finished, the thread terminate automatically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're apparently trying to `join()` the current thread (you can see this for yourself if you replace `myJob.join()` with `System.out.println( Thread.currentThread() )`), which isn't a very good idea, as the thread will be stuck forever, or until someone else interrupts it from the outside.

Instead of `join()`, just call `interrupt()`, there's nothing shameful about that. (Although whether it will have any effect depends on what else is in `runMyJob()`)

Update: I can only assume that you edited out parts of your code for brevity, but if `MyController` really does nothing else if it encounters the exit value `123` than to stop the updating thread, then the whole construction is unnecessary. You should simply return from the `runMyJob()` method without setting anything and the thread will stop gracefully.

Comment: Calling `interrupt()` doesn't actually stop the thread, right?  It just sets the interrupted flag on the `Thread` object.

Comment: @Gray That's true, it will depend on the redacted part of the code whether it'll have any effect or not. As it stands, you don't even need interrupt, the thread will terminate normally by itself if left alone.

Comment: Roger.  I was mostly speaking for posterity.  So many programmers thing `interrupt()` is the new `cancel()`.

Comment: I think that I can call safely .interrupt(). IHMO isn't an elegant solution, but I think that is the unique in this case..Another solution is .start() and .join() but myJob in this example is only one, but in my code I do a List of job, so start()/join() can block the spawn of others threads (myJob in this case)..

Comment: You can also throw a custom exception from your observer (provided that there aren't any other observers around that have to be called first), catch it in `MyJob` and return. There are other, even more contrived solutions as well but I don't think you're going to need them.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have some logic errors here:

1. In `runMyJob()` you are calling `model.changeStatus(123)`
2. That calls `notifyObservers()` in `Observable`
3. That notifies the observers by calling `MyController.update()`
4. That then tries to `join()` on the thread.

Since the thread is the one that is calling the `update()` then it is trying to join with itself which obviously won't work.  I'd have the main thread just do a join after the start:

```
myJob.start();
myJob.join();
```

You could also set some sort of value during the update (maybe a `volatile int` or `AtomicInteger`) that then can be read by the main thread.

If you edit your question to let us know what you are trying to accomplish, I'll adjust my answer to provide some better recommendations.